# How to create a container that can turn into a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, containers

I am using a for loop to print a series of samples. I want to write in a container that stores those samples, so that each sample that is printed x number of times according to the for loop is saved. Ultimately, I want the container to create and save a matrix.

For example, if the for loop's output is :

```
1  2  3  4  5
2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  8  10
```

I want a container to print save a matrix that looks like that.

Here is the code I have so far. Am I on the right track?

```
for (i in 1:5){
oneA <- round(rnorm(5, mean = 5, sd = 1))
oneAVec <- c(oneA)
print(oneAVec)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to initialize a `list` to store the output

```
oneA <- vector("list", 5)
for(i in seq_len(5)) {
   oneA[[i]] <- round(rnorm(5, mean= 5, sd = 1))
   print(c(oneA[[i]]))
 }
```